# want help in textbox condition to display value in php

Tags: php

I have a little task about displaying a textbox value in which I have to type something in a text box and it will display it with some additional text.

For example, if I type stackoverflow then it will display `I love: stackoverflow` and if I leave the text box empty the page should not display anything, not even `I love:`

My attempt is below, but it still displays `I love:` even when the text box is empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="txt" autocomplete='off' placeholder="Enter Your Value" ></td></tr>
```

php code to display

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['txt'])) {echo "I love:" . $_POST['txt'];} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['txt']) && $_POST['txt'] != "") {
    echo "I love:" . $_POST['txt'];
}
```